# Require [Authorize] for all actions in Asp.Mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, authorization

Is there a elegant way to require all actions to require [Authorize] without having to use an AOP framework or similar? It seems to easy too forget to put the attribute on all controllers.
I guess creating a base controller also can solve this, but again.. It's possible to forget to inherit from this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting it on the base controller is the easiest thing to do.  To enforce compliance, you could write a unit test which enumerates over all the Controller types in your application and does a check to make sure that they subclass your CustomControllerBase.